# How to finish this sql opreation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to page table A while selecting rows in B!!!!!

I hava to table named A and B
data in A is unique, but complex in B.
e.g.:

**Table A:**

```
id user
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

**Table B:**

```
id nickname
1  aa
1  aaa
1  aaaa
2  bb
2  bbb
3  cc
```

**My expectation:**

```
id user nickname
1  a    aa
1  a    aaa
1  a    aaaa
2  b    bb
2  b    bbb
```

Now I want to select 2 rows in A each time, but all rows in B where A.id=B.id.
How to program?

my original sql:

```
select * from A, B where A.id=B.id limit 2;
return:
id user nickname
1  a    aa
1  a    aaa
```

Its not my expectation.

As 2 steps:

```
1.
select id from A limit 2 offset 0
2.
for id in selected_A
    select * from B where B.id=selected_A.id
```

---

Here is the one solution:

```
select * from B join (select * from A limit 2 offset 0) as A on A.id=B.id
```

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: A simple join? `select *
from a 
  join b using (id)`

Comment: Try my answer, it will helps you.

Comment: @DineshDB The point is not the ID<=2, it is paging!!!

Comment: @yanwii, yes. But I changed it already in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JOINS`, you can achieve this easily.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Id,A.User, B.NickName
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM A ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2);
```